# block UI not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, blockui

why this code not working? 
I set cookie when download a file into fileDownloadToken. and check it if not null then exec finishdownload ...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
    function blockUIForDownload() {
        if (IsCookiesEnable()) {
            var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value
            $('#token').val(token);
            $.blockUI{ message: '', fadeIn: 0 };);
            fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
               // alert(cookieValue);
                if (cookieValue != null)
                    finishDownload();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function IsCookiesEnable() {
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = "testcookie";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        }
        return (cookieEnabled);
    }

    function finishDownload() {
        //window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null);
        $.unblockUI();
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug the JavaScript? Can you tell it there is an exception?

Comment: Please define the not working, by tell us what is your problem exactly, and what you believe that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$.blockUI{ message: '', fadeIn: 0 };);
```

to

```
$.blockUI({ message: '', fadeIn: 0});
```